# Translating functional dependencies into 3rd normal form

Tags: database, normalization, relational-database, 3nf

I have this problem decomposing a relation schema into a set of schemas that are in 3NF.

I have this relation schema: R= (A, B, C, D, E, F)
With the following set F of functional dependencies:

A → ABCDEF
B → C
D → E

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: How do you think this should be broken down? Show us your effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R<sub>A</sub> = (A, B, D, F)
R<sub>B</sub> = (B, C)
R<sub>D</sub> = (D, E)

Why?  3NF requires the removal all transitive dependencies.

In R, C is transitively dependent on A through B, and the same is true for E through D.  To remove those properties, you need to decompose the tables such that those transitive relationships are removed, which you do by extracting the table and using the middle term as keys.

Comment: 3NF requires absence of transitive dependencies of non-prime attributes on CKs (not absence of transitive dependencies); although that is not enough; additionally being in 2NF is sufficient.